# Есть ли разница между передачей значений через список захвата и через аргументы лямбды? С++

Tags: c++, lambda, лямбда-выражение

У нас есть некоторая лямбда:

```
std::int64_t a = /*....*/;
std::int64_t b = /*....*/;
std::thread{[](){ /* do something */ }};
```

Есть ли разница в производительности, если я буду передавать в лямбду значения следующими способами:

```
std::thread{[a, b](){ /* do something */ }};
std::thread{[](std::int64_t a, std::int64_t b){ /* do something */ }, a, b};
```

Концептуально понятно, что в случае передачи через список захвата таким образом, значения будут копироваться и записываться во внутреннем состоянии лямбды. Кроме того без mutable их нельзя будет изменить. Но как это влияет на производительность и на поведение "под коробкой"?

Comment: Если вы можете выбирать между двумя сигнатурами (обычно это невозможно, что делает ваш вопрос странным), то производительность не изменится. Грубо говоря, компилятор видит одни и те же данные, один и тот же код (очень похожий код) и имеет одни и те же возможности для оптимизации.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy а как же то, что при наличии чего-либо в списке захвата, лямбда станет не указателем на функцию, а объектом? Это не повлияет ни на что?

Comment: Вы сейчас говорите о накладных расходах на один вызов. Это ничто в сравнении с созданием нити. Если ваша функция столь легка что вы можете заметить разницу в вызовах, то вы уже убили производительность задействовав `std::thread`.

Comment: То что лямбда стала объектом означает что под капотом в функцию передаётся указатель на структуру с захваченными значениями. Что-то вроде `this`. Не о чем говорить.